# Libgdx player trails

Tags: java, libgdx, particle-system, topdown

I am making a top down 2D skiing game, and I want to add a trail for the player that follows him around. I've considered trying to use particles, however I realize that this would be hard to make and it might make gaps. Are there any other methods of doing this other than using the particle system?